# Xml to Java Class using JAXBContext

Tags: java, xml, rest, web-services, reflection

I have created several REST Web Services that will return list of records, from my database.

I'm returning all query results in XML format and in my Web service methods I convert it to Java to send it to my client app in JSON (I know, not the best case).

I'm trying to reduce the code in my methods an part of the code that I started with was the XML to Java conversion.

Right now I'm using the following

```
String xml = xml.replaceFirst("ROWSET xmlns:xsi = " + "\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", "invTrxXmlList");  
String string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";  
xml = string.concat(xml);  
xml = xml.replaceAll("ROWSET", "invTrxXmlList");  
xml = xml.replaceAll("ROW", "invTrxXmlList");  
xml = xml.replaceAll(" xsi:nil = \"true\"", "");  
InputStream instr = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());  
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InvTrxXmlList.class);  
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
InvTrxXmlList invTrxXml = (InvTrxXmlList) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(instr);  

inventoryTrx = new InventoryTrx(invTrxXml);
```

What I want is to create a separate method that could be called by all methods to this job, if possible to work with several distinct Custom Objects, like InvTrxXmlList.

I have, in another task worked a little with Reflection and i was thinking of using it to solve this issue.

Can you help me?

Is there another approach?

Thanks

Comment: You will have to create a http post methods, and pass the list within its body. I'm not sure what you made it so complicated

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I'm only using XML because the database version that I have won't yet use JSON and I'm unable to update it, and I don't want to change all my services and client app to consume XML.
What I want is to reduce the amount of code that is duplicated, and this block is several times duplicated since my pkg list functions will always return XML.
Now if there is a way that I can instantiate an object (dynamically), I have several distinct objects, sending the name or even an instantiated object from the caller and then fill it with the data from my XML that would be great.

Comment: create a java class 1.@Path("/product")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks silfrede,

I was able to put it to work with the following code

```
public Object xmlToJava(Object pCurrentObject, String pXml, String pRowset, String pRow) {
    InputStream  instr = null;
    JAXBContext  jaxbContext = null;
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = null;

    String xmlHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    String xmlReturn = null;
    Class  objectClass = pCurrentObject.getClass();
    try {
        xmlReturn =
            pXml.replaceFirst("ROWSET xmlns:xsi = " +
                              "\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"",
                              pRowset); //"invTrxLines");

        xmlReturn = xmlHeader.concat(xmlReturn);
        xmlReturn = xmlReturn.replaceAll("ROWSET", pRowset); //"invTrxLines");

        if (null != pRow && !pRow.isEmpty()) {
            xmlReturn = xmlReturn.replaceAll("ROW", pRow); //invTrxLine);
        } else { //Remove Row tags in case of single object
            xmlReturn = xmlReturn.replaceAll("<ROW>", "");
            xmlReturn = xmlReturn.replaceAll("</ROW>", "");
        }

        xmlReturn = xmlReturn.replaceAll(" xsi:nil = \"true\"", "");
        instr = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlReturn.getBytes());
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(objectClass); //InvTrxHead.class);
        jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        pCurrentObject = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(instr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: Add catch code
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pCurrentObject;
}
```

with the following call

```
invTrxHead = (InvTrxHead) WSUtils.xmlToJava(invTrxHead, invTrxHeadXml, "invTrxHead", null);
```

Now I can sen my XML from my DB and an instance of my object and don't have to duplicate any of the code.